# Save redis hash instead of string

Tags: python, redis

I can save a dict as a string in redis as follows:

```
>>> r.set( 
           'rt.http://rottentomatoes.com/m/771354525/', 
           {"Director": "blasco ricardo", "Platform": "RT"}
         )
```

How would I save the dict as a dict/hash directly so I wouldn't have to use `json.loads` to read it into a dict? Currently, if I do `r.get()` I get the dict as a string:

```
>>> r.get('rt.http://rottentomatoes.com/m/771354525/')
'{"Director": "blasco ricardo", "Platform": "RT"}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [hmset](http://redis.io/commands/hmset)

```
HMSET 'rt.http://rottentomatoes.com/m/771354525/' Director "blasco ricardo" Platform "RT"
```

Then you can retrieve it with

```
HGETALL rt.http://rottentomatoes.com/m/771354525/
```

Or a specific field with

```
HGET rt.http://rottentomatoes.com/m/771354525/ Director
```

In python it would be

```
r.hmset('rt.http://rottentomatoes.com/m/771354525/', {'Director': 'blasco ricardo', 'Platform': 'RT'})
r.hgetall('rt.http://rottentomatoes.com/m/771354525/')
r.hget('rt.http://rottentomatoes.com/m/771354525/', 'Director')
```